# How to parse the Xml Data...?

Tags: android, xml, parsing

i am new at android Native coding and i have xml response coming from my webservice and i am confused. How to parse the xml data and insert the data into  String array.. I a have below response coming from server..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <soap:Body>
  <GetActiveThemeListResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <GetActiveThemeListResult>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
           <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
              <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="ActiveThemeList">
                       <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                             <xs:element name="ThemeName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          </xs:sequence>
                       </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                 </xs:choice>
              </xs:complexType>
           </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
           <NewDataSet xmlns="">
              <ActiveThemeList diffgr:id="ActiveThemeList1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                 <ThemeName>sample</ThemeName>
              </ActiveThemeList>
              <ActiveThemeList diffgr:id="ActiveThemeList2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                 <ThemeName>magic</ThemeName>
              </ActiveThemeList>
              <ActiveThemeList diffgr:id="ActiveThemeList3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
                 <ThemeName>travel</ThemeName>
              </ActiveThemeList>
           </NewDataSet>
        </diffgr:diffgram>
     </GetActiveThemeListResult>
  </GetActiveThemeListResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How do i fetch the data of second child node `NewDataSet`
I neeed to insert the `ThemeName` node value `sample` into array [];
i need to store the data as below:

`Ex:[sample, magic, travel]`

AnyBody help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jsoup

*(Download from [here](http://jsoup.org/download) -- just add the jar to your project. If you have any trouble, just let me know)*

To use it, you would write:

```
 List<String> themes = new ArrayList<String>();

 // Parse the XML to create a DOM
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(yourXmlAsAString);

 // Use the select method to select all ThemeName tags
 for (Element elem: doc.select("ThemeName")){

     // Use the text method to get the inner text
     themes.add(elem.text());
 }
```

If you want to ensure that Jsoup only selects `ThemeName` tags that are a child of `NewDataSet`, replace

```
for (Element elem: doc.select("ThemeName")){
```

with

```
for (Element elem: doc.select("NewDataSet > ThemeName")){
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using XmlPullParser. The advantage of it is relatively simple API compared to SAX and DOM and is fast and requires less memory then the DOM API. Please read [the google doc here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) 
Example how to use it

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException.html;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

 public class SimpleXmlPullApp
 {

     public static void main (String args[])
         throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
     {
         XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
         factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
         XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

         xpp.setInput(new StringReader ("<foo>Hello World!</foo>"));
         int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
         while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
          if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
              System.out.println("Start document");
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
              System.out.println("End document");
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
              System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
              System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
              System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
          }
          eventType = xpp.next();
         }
     }
 }
```